# What happens when you reboot an instance store based Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance, with **instance store** root device (i.e., not EBS), running Linux (Ubuntu).

What happens if I restart the instance like so:

```
sudo reboot
```

- Will the instance storage still be there after reboot, or does it get wiped?
- How about the public IP address of the EC2 instance (assuming an Elastic IP is *not* used): does it change or stay the same?
- If an Elastic IP *is* used, will it still be associated with this instance after reboot?

Comment: (I realise this is kinda basic AWS question, but a google search didn't immediately answer it so I figured it should be documented on SF.)

Comment: It's a basic question, but you're right in that there really isn't a clear cut answer that isn't confusing (that I've found) in Amazon's documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, the instance store will still be there after reboot, intact.

Also, yes, the IP address stays the same. (<s>But if an Elastic IP was used, you'll need to re-associate it with the instance, if I recall correctly.</s> Also Elastic IP is retained, as [Matt Houser points out](https://serverfault.com/a/396413/1746).)

Answer (score 8):

If you reboot your instance, it's not moved to new hardware, and the instance store should still be there.

Also, since the instance is not being stopped, then the elastic IP should persist. Only if the instance is stopped will the elastic IP be disassociated.

Comment: Hi Matt, will the Elastic IP also get changed or it will be the same and we just want to associate it?

Comment: @Shihas I address the Elastic IP in my answer.